# prove that $\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ca}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\geq a+b+c$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c>0$, Then prove that $$\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ca}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\geq a+b+c$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using Cauchy- Schwarz Inequality

$$\frac{a^4}{abc}+\frac{b^4}{abc}+\frac{c^4}{abc}\geq \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3abc}$$

Now How can i solve after that , Help required, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a^4+b^4+c^4\geq a^2bc+b^2ac+c^2 ab $$
holds by the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) or [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use Holder's inequality for three variables in the following way:

$$(b+c+a)(c+a+b) \Big(\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ca}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\Big) \geqslant (a+b+c)^3 $$

From where you get:
$$ \frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ca}+\frac{c^3}{ab} \geqslant a+b+c$$